# HttpClient Custom redirection handler for relative redirection

Tags: java, android, redirect, apache-commons-httpclient

Is there a way to make a custom redirection handler which tells the Apache HttpClient where i want to be redirected before the redirection occurs, after a post method execution? This because i get an error in the response page and my guess is this is due to a relative redirection, that's not interpreted correctly. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'redirected before the redirection occurs', but you can create your own redirection handler and replace the default one. Then you can handle the `Location` header  however you like. In any case if the default one doesn't handle it correctly, it most likely some server misconfiguration. Here's the interface an the default implementation for reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/RedirectHandler.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultRedirectHandler.html

Comment: sorry but i need your help again, i'm trying with this, i implemented RedirectHandler and now i was looking for some sample code online to handle the Location header like you said, i couldn't find any, so... maybe in isRedirectRequested() method i should do something with response object? Thank you for your patience

Comment: Look at the source of `DefaultRedirectHandler` for hints. It checks the status code in `isRedirectRequested()` and returns `true` for 301, 302, etc. Then `getLocationURI()` extracts the `Location` header and returns the URL to go to next. It does handle relative and absolute for you, so log the headers and the location and compare to what  you are expecting. Then adjust as necessary.